# How to edit MS Frontpage 2003 Site Parameters manually

Tags: frontpage, frontpage-extensions

I'm switching from Frontpage 2003 to Expression Web 4 and have a lot of Site Parameters (merge variables) I want to be able to maintain.

There doesn't seem to be support for that in EW 4. Can I edit them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more elegant solution. You can edit the FrontPage Site Parameters manually. They're in a text file in :
**root\vti_pvt\service.cnf**

You can add additional variables and edit the ones that are there. Format is fairly clear from the file structure (something like: Variable name:value which can have spaces

Comment: You answered your own question immediately after posting it.

Comment: Yep, that's an option offered by SO.

Comment: It should give you an indication that you _shouldnt_ have asked it in the first place.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, Joel Spolsky has repeadely said that the purpose of SO is to be a repository of canonical answers. It doesn't matter *how* the answers get there. He (and I think Jeff Atwood) have used this very type of situation (answering your own question) as an example.  The feature (answering your own question) is there to be used, not to discourage you from using it.